# iPhone GPS speed calculation issue

Tags: ios4

In my application, I am using LocationManager for getting location, also I want calculate DISTANCE, SPEED and TIME.

From Location manager I am getting time and distance successfully,But when I calculate the speed from coordinates it is showing wrong values.

For getting location I am using following code.

```
CLLocationManager *locManager ;
float fltDistanceTravelled; 
double calculatedSpeed;

//===============
locManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locManager.delegate=self;
locManager.distanceFilter=25.0f;
locManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
[locManager startUpdatingLocation];
//=====================

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
    if(newLocation && oldLocation)
    {
        // getting distance
        fltDistanceTravelled +=[self getDistanceInKm:newLocation fromLocation:oldLocation];
    }
    if(oldLocation != nil)         
    {
        CLLocationDistance distanceChange = [newLocation getDistanceFrom:oldLocation];
        NSTimeInterval sinceLastUpdate = [newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate:oldLocation.timestamp];
        // calculate speed
        calculatedSpeed= (distanceChange / sinceLastUpdate) * 3.6;       
    }
}
```

but this code return wrong values  of calculatedSpeed (speed) of the car.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already getting the speed data in the delegate method.

[`CLLocation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126) has a `speed` property

Rather than try and calculate it yourself, just get it from `newLocation.speed`.

Comment: I am getting same but sometime it return wrong values
I am using following code for calculating the speeds.          
 CLLocationDistance distanceChange = [newLocation getDistanceFrom:oldLocation];
        NSTimeInterval sinceLastUpdate = [newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate:oldLocation.timestamp];
        // calculate speed
        calculatedSpeed= (distanceChange / sinceLastUpdate) * 3.6;

Comment: @nivrutti The point I was trying to make is that you don't need to calculate speed - you can get it from the `speed` property of `CLLocation` directly.

Comment: thanks @Abizern   ok I will use only GPS Speed in my app ,but sometime it return minus values

Comment: Those are invalid values. But considering that you are getting the value with high frequency it provides the same sort of information. To get smoother values - you could take the value separated by slightly longer time and average them out.